# QGIS: batch assigning CRS for point clouds

Tags: qgis, point-cloud, pdal

I got a bunch of LAZ compressed point cloud tiles (over 300). They don't have a projection assigned. I want to assign the correct projection (I know the files are in EPSG:25832) with the action "Assign projection" in QGIS from the toolbox. When I try to run it as batch action, QGIS asks me for the projection of every file. I have set the CRS for every file.

[image: Screenshot of the batch processing tool]

This is exactly why I want to assign a projection! Is this a bug or intended behavior? And how can I just assign a projection without getting asked? I don't want to double-click on "EPSG:25832" 300-times.

It seems like QGIS is indexing every point cloud it loads:
[image: QGIS processing a point cloud]

So assigning a CRS in QGIS doesn't help, as it loads the LAZ-file without CRS anyway.

Comment: Which QGIS Version do you use?

Comment: QGIS 3.34.3, installed with OSGeo4W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in "CRS and Transforms/CRS Handling/CRS for Layers":

Set it to "Leave as an unknown CRS (take no action)" to prevent QGIS prompting for a CRS selction.

[image: Options for CRS handling]